# Next/previous post link to posts only within one or more specific categories

Tags: next-post-link, previous-post-link

I have posts that are in multiple categories. I am showing a next/previous post link on posts that are in a specific category, regardless of how many other categories this post has. The links are now to posts that are in any of the categories that the post is in. I want to only link to the next/previous post in one of the categories the post is in.

I found a function online that I have tried to change to suit my needs. This is in my functions.php file:

```
//Next and previous post logic
function get_excluded_categories() {
   // Get categories of current post
   $current_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category' );
   // Declare array to store excluded categories
   $excluded_cats = [];
   // Loop through current categories
   foreach( $current_cats as $cat ) {
      // Check if current category is included
      $this_cat = $cat->slug;
      if($this_cat !== '[SLUG]') {
          // If it is not, add it's term ID to the excluded array
          array_push($excluded_cats, $cat->term_id);
      }
   }
   return $excluded_cats;
}
```

This is how I display the links:

```
<?php if (in_category('[SLUG]')) : ?>
            <div class = "next-post"><?php next_post_link('%link &raquo;', '%title', true, get_excluded_categories()); ?></div>
            <div class = "prev-post"><?php previous_post_link('&laquo; %link', '%title', true, get_excluded_categories()); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is not working quite as expected. Only one link shows up, either the next or the previous post link. If I have only two posts in the category, this is fine and expected behavior. But if I have three posts, I want to have only the next link on the first, the next and previous links on the middle post and only the previous link on the last post.

<s>Right now it seems to just skip over any existing posts in between the first and last.</s> It is actually not the posts "in between" that are skipped over, but the second post does not have a link to the third post. If I go manually into the third post, it has a previous link to the first post and not the second as expected.

I know I have probably got my logic wrong, but I don't understand how, where or why.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this because WordPress is going:

"Does this post have category X?"

Rather than:

"Let's not look through this category since that is excluded"

Because the former is really disregarding the fact that posts can be in several categories at once.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by abandoning the code and registering a new taxonomy. I then used this code in single.php:

```
<?php if (has_term('[TERM-NAME]', '[TAXONOMY-NAME]')) : ?>
        <div class = "next-post"><?php next_post_link('%link &raquo;', '%title', true, '', '[TAXONOMY-NAME]') ?></div>
        <div class = "prev-post"><?php previous_post_link('&laquo; %link', '%title', true, '', '[TAXONOMY-NAME') ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Doing it like this allows me to have multiple categories since I only assign one term in the custom taxonomy per post.